# how to execute batch apex

Tags: batch

```
global class DailyLeadProcessor implements
    Database.Batchable<sobject> {
        global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc)
        {
            string query = 'select name,leadsource from lead';
            return Database.getQueryLocator(query); 
        }
        global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, list<lead> scope)
        {
            for(lead l:scope)
            {
                l.LeadSource = 'Dreamforce';
            }
            update scope;
        }
        global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
        {

        } 
}
```

Comment: Do you want to just execute this class once or schedule it daily?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To run batch Apex, go to User Menu --> Developer Console.

In the Apex Code section,

```
DailyLeadProcessor  M = new DailyLeadProcessor();
Database.executeBatch(M);
```

where DailyLeadProcessor is a Batch Apex Class

Answer (score 0):

```
@isTest
public class DailyLeadProcessor_TEST {
       static testMethod void UnitTestBatch(){
           Lead l = new Lead();
           l.leadsource = 'Dreamforce';
           entered required fields ..
           insert l;
           Test.startTest();
           DailyLeadProcessor  DLP = new DailyLeadProcessor();
           Database.executeBatch(DLP,10);
          System.assert(set the assert to validate the class code');
           Test.stopTest();

       }
}
```